# How to load Google web fonts listing dynamically into an array?

Tags: php, webfonts

I would like to pull a feed of the entire Google web fonts collection, and collect them into an array with this structure (font collection => font name):

```
<?php
$googleFonts = array
(
"" => "None",
"Abel"=>"Abel",
"Abril Fatface"=>"Abril Fatface",
"Aclonica"=>"Aclonica",
"Actor"=>"Actor",
"Astloch:regular,bold"=>"Astloch (plus bold)",
//...etc
)
?>
```

Does an API exist to grab the fonts in this manner?

Comment: Look here: http://code.google.com/apis/webfonts/docs/developer_api.html

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure if you're looking for an array, but the most recent output (10th March 2013) from Google, took me 3 hours to work this out, If this array helps ?

```
$googlefonts = array("ABeeZee" => "ABeeZee",
"Abel" => "Abel",
"Abril Fatface" => "Abril+Fatface",
"Aclonica" => "Aclonica",
"Acme" => "Acme",
"Actor" => "Actor",
"Adamina" => "Adamina",
"Advent Pro" => "Advent+Pro",
"Aguafina Script" => "Aguafina+Script",
"Akronim" => "Akronim",
"Aladin" => "Aladin",
"Aldrich" => "Aldrich",
"Alegreya" => "Alegreya",
"Alegreya SC" => "Alegreya+SC",
"Alex Brush" => "Alex+Brush",
"Alfa Slab One" => "Alfa+Slab+One",
"Alice" => "Alice",
"Alike" => "Alike",
"Alike Angular" => "Alike+Angular",
"Allan" => "Allan",
"Allerta" => "Allerta",
"Allerta Stencil" => "Allerta+Stencil",
"Allura" => "Allura",
"Almendra" => "Almendra",
"Almendra Display" => "Almendra+Display",
"Almendra SC" => "Almendra+SC",
"Amarante" => "Amarante",
"Amaranth" => "Amaranth",
"Amatic SC" => "Amatic+SC",
"Amethysta" => "Amethysta",
"Anaheim" => "Anaheim",
"Andada" => "Andada",
"Andika" => "Andika",
"Angkor" => "Angkor",
"Annie Use Your Telescope" => "Annie+Use+Your+Telescope",
"Anonymous Pro" => "Anonymous+Pro",
"Antic" => "Antic",
"Antic Didone" => "Antic+Didone",
"Antic Slab" => "Antic+Slab",
"Anton" => "Anton",
"Arapey" => "Arapey",
"Arbutus" => "Arbutus",
"Arbutus Slab" => "Arbutus+Slab",
"Architects Daughter" => "Architects+Daughter",
"Archivo Black" => "Archivo+Black",
"Archivo Narrow" => "Archivo+Narrow",
"Arimo" => "Arimo",
"Arizonia" => "Arizonia",
"Armata" => "Armata",
"Artifika" => "Artifika",
"Arvo" => "Arvo",
"Asap" => "Asap",
"Asset" => "Asset",
"Astloch" => "Astloch",
"Asul" => "Asul",
"Atomic Age" => "Atomic+Age",
"Aubrey" => "Aubrey",
"Audiowide" => "Audiowide",
"Autour One" => "Autour+One",
"Average" => "Average",
"Average Sans" => "Average+Sans",
"Averia Gruesa Libre" => "Averia+Gruesa+Libre",
"Averia Libre" => "Averia+Libre",
"Averia Sans Libre" => "Averia+Sans+Libre",
"Averia Serif Libre" => "Averia+Serif+Libre",
"Bad Script" => "Bad+Script",
"Balthazar" => "Balthazar",
"Bangers" => "Bangers",
"Basic" => "Basic",
"Battambang" => "Battambang",
"Baumans" => "Baumans",
"Bayon" => "Bayon",
"Belgrano" => "Belgrano",
"Belleza" => "Belleza",
"BenchNine" => "BenchNine",
"Bentham" => "Bentham",
"Berkshire Swash" => "Berkshire+Swash",
"Bevan" => "Bevan",
"Bigelow Rules" => "Bigelow+Rules",
"Bigshot One" => "Bigshot+One",
"Bilbo" => "Bilbo",
"Bilbo Swash Caps" => "Bilbo+Swash+Caps",
"Bitter" => "Bitter",
"Black Ops One" => "Black+Ops+One",
"Bokor" => "Bokor",
"Bonbon" => "Bonbon",
"Boogaloo" => "Boogaloo",
"Bowlby One" => "Bowlby+One",
"Bowlby One SC" => "Bowlby+One+SC",
"Brawler" => "Brawler",
"Bree Serif" => "Bree+Serif",
"Bubblegum Sans" => "Bubblegum+Sans",
"Bubbler One" => "Bubbler+One",
"Buda" => "Buda",
"Buenard" => "Buenard",
"Butcherman" => "Butcherman",
"Butterfly Kids" => "Butterfly+Kids",
"Cabin" => "Cabin",
"Cabin Condensed" => "Cabin+Condensed",
"Cabin Sketch" => "Cabin+Sketch",
"Caesar Dressing" => "Caesar+Dressing",
"Cagliostro" => "Cagliostro",
"Calligraffitti" => "Calligraffitti",
"Cambo" => "Cambo",
"Candal" => "Candal",
"Cantarell" => "Cantarell",
"Cantata One" => "Cantata+One",
"Cantora One" => "Cantora+One",
"Capriola" => "Capriola",
"Cardo" => "Cardo",
"Carme" => "Carme",
"Carrois Gothic" => "Carrois+Gothic",
"Carrois Gothic SC" => "Carrois+Gothic+SC",
"Carter One" => "Carter+One",
"Caudex" => "Caudex",
"Cedarville Cursive" => "Cedarville+Cursive",
"Ceviche One" => "Ceviche+One",
"Changa One" => "Changa+One",
"Chango" => "Chango",
"Chau Philomene One" => "Chau+Philomene+One",
"Chela One" => "Chela+One",
"Chelsea Market" => "Chelsea+Market",
"Chenla" => "Chenla",
"Cherry Cream Soda" => "Cherry+Cream+Soda",
"Cherry Swash" => "Cherry+Swash",
"Chewy" => "Chewy",
"Chicle" => "Chicle",
"Chivo" => "Chivo",
"Cinzel" => "Cinzel",
"Cinzel Decorative" => "Cinzel+Decorative",
"Clicker Script" => "Clicker+Script",
"Coda" => "Coda",
"Coda Caption" => "Coda+Caption",
"Codystar" => "Codystar",
"Combo" => "Combo",
"Comfortaa" => "Comfortaa",
"Coming Soon" => "Coming+Soon",
"Concert One" => "Concert+One",
"Condiment" => "Condiment",
"Content" => "Content",
"Contrail One" => "Contrail+One",
"Convergence" => "Convergence",
"Cookie" => "Cookie",
"Copse" => "Copse",
"Corben" => "Corben",
"Courgette" => "Courgette",
"Cousine" => "Cousine",
"Coustard" => "Coustard",
"Covered By Your Grace" => "Covered+By+Your+Grace",
"Crafty Girls" => "Crafty+Girls",
"Creepster" => "Creepster",
"Crete Round" => "Crete+Round",
"Crimson Text" => "Crimson+Text",
"Croissant One" => "Croissant+One",
"Crushed" => "Crushed",
"Cuprum" => "Cuprum",
"Cutive" => "Cutive",
"Cutive Mono" => "Cutive+Mono",
"Damion" => "Damion",
"Dancing Script" => "Dancing+Script",
"Dangrek" => "Dangrek",
"Dawning of a New Day" => "Dawning+of+a+New+Day",
"Days One" => "Days+One",
"Delius" => "Delius",
"Delius Swash Caps" => "Delius+Swash+Caps",
"Delius Unicase" => "Delius+Unicase",
"Della Respira" => "Della+Respira",
"Denk One" => "Denk+One",
"Devonshire" => "Devonshire",
"Didact Gothic" => "Didact+Gothic",
"Diplomata" => "Diplomata",
"Diplomata SC" => "Diplomata+SC",
"Domine" => "Domine",
"Donegal One" => "Donegal+One",
"Doppio One" => "Doppio+One",
"Dorsa" => "Dorsa",
"Dosis" => "Dosis",
"Dr Sugiyama" => "Dr+Sugiyama",
"Droid Sans" => "Droid+Sans",
"Droid Sans Mono" => "Droid+Sans+Mono",
"Droid Serif" => "Droid+Serif",
"Duru Sans" => "Duru+Sans",
"Dynalight" => "Dynalight",
"EB Garamond" => "EB+Garamond",
"Eagle Lake" => "Eagle+Lake",
"Eater" => "Eater",
"Economica" => "Economica",
"Electrolize" => "Electrolize",
"Elsie" => "Elsie",
"Elsie Swash Caps" => "Elsie+Swash+Caps",
"Emblema One" => "Emblema+One",
"Emilys Candy" => "Emilys+Candy",
"Engagement" => "Engagement",
"Englebert" => "Englebert",
"Enriqueta" => "Enriqueta",
"Erica One" => "Erica+One",
"Esteban" => "Esteban",
"Euphoria Script" => "Euphoria+Script",
"Ewert" => "Ewert",
"Exo" => "Exo",
"Expletus Sans" => "Expletus+Sans",
"Fanwood Text" => "Fanwood+Text",
"Fascinate" => "Fascinate",
"Fascinate Inline" => "Fascinate+Inline",
"Faster One" => "Faster+One",
"Fasthand" => "Fasthand",
"Federant" => "Federant",
"Federo" => "Federo",
"Felipa" => "Felipa",
"Fenix" => "Fenix",
"Finger Paint" => "Finger+Paint",
"Fjalla One" => "Fjalla+One",
"Fjord One" => "Fjord+One",
"Flamenco" => "Flamenco",
"Flavors" => "Flavors",
"Fondamento" => "Fondamento",
"Fontdiner Swanky" => "Fontdiner+Swanky",
"Forum" => "Forum",
"Francois One" => "Francois+One",
"Freckle Face" => "Freckle+Face",
"Fredericka the Great" => "Fredericka+the+Great",
"Fredoka One" => "Fredoka+One",
"Freehand" => "Freehand",
"Fresca" => "Fresca",
"Frijole" => "Frijole",
"Fruktur" => "Fruktur",
"Fugaz One" => "Fugaz+One",
"GFS Didot" => "GFS+Didot",
"GFS Neohellenic" => "GFS+Neohellenic",
"Gabriela" => "Gabriela",
"Gafata" => "Gafata",
"Galdeano" => "Galdeano",
"Galindo" => "Galindo",
"Gentium Basic" => "Gentium+Basic",
"Gentium Book Basic" => "Gentium+Book+Basic",
"Geo" => "Geo",
"Geostar" => "Geostar",
"Geostar Fill" => "Geostar+Fill",
"Germania One" => "Germania+One",
"Gilda Display" => "Gilda+Display",
"Give You Glory" => "Give+You+Glory",
"Glass Antiqua" => "Glass+Antiqua",
"Glegoo" => "Glegoo",
"Gloria Hallelujah" => "Gloria+Hallelujah",
"Goblin One" => "Goblin+One",
"Gochi Hand" => "Gochi+Hand",
"Gorditas" => "Gorditas",
"Goudy Bookletter 1911" => "Goudy+Bookletter+1911",
"Graduate" => "Graduate",
"Grand Hotel" => "Grand+Hotel",
"Gravitas One" => "Gravitas+One",
"Great Vibes" => "Great+Vibes",
"Griffy" => "Griffy",
"Gruppo" => "Gruppo",
"Gudea" => "Gudea",
"Habibi" => "Habibi",
"Hammersmith One" => "Hammersmith+One",
"Hanalei" => "Hanalei",
"Hanalei Fill" => "Hanalei+Fill",
"Handlee" => "Handlee",
"Hanuman" => "Hanuman",
"Happy Monkey" => "Happy+Monkey",
"Headland One" => "Headland+One",
"Henny Penny" => "Henny+Penny",
"Herr Von Muellerhoff" => "Herr+Von+Muellerhoff",
"Holtwood One SC" => "Holtwood+One+SC",
"Homemade Apple" => "Homemade+Apple",
"Homenaje" => "Homenaje",
"IM Fell DW Pica" => "IM+Fell+DW+Pica",
"IM Fell DW Pica SC" => "IM+Fell+DW+Pica+SC",
"IM Fell Double Pica" => "IM+Fell+Double+Pica",
"IM Fell Double Pica SC" => "IM+Fell+Double+Pica+SC",
"IM Fell English" => "IM+Fell+English",
"IM Fell English SC" => "IM+Fell+English+SC",
"IM Fell French Canon" => "IM+Fell+French+Canon",
"IM Fell French Canon SC" => "IM+Fell+French+Canon+SC",
"IM Fell Great Primer" => "IM+Fell+Great+Primer",
"IM Fell Great Primer SC" => "IM+Fell+Great+Primer+SC",
"Iceberg" => "Iceberg",
"Iceland" => "Iceland",
"Imprima" => "Imprima",
"Inconsolata" => "Inconsolata",
"Inder" => "Inder",
"Indie Flower" => "Indie+Flower",
"Inika" => "Inika",
"Irish Grover" => "Irish+Grover",
"Istok Web" => "Istok+Web",
"Italiana" => "Italiana",
"Italianno" => "Italianno",
"Jacques Francois" => "Jacques+Francois",
"Jacques Francois Shadow" => "Jacques+Francois+Shadow",
"Jim Nightshade" => "Jim+Nightshade",
"Jockey One" => "Jockey+One",
"Jolly Lodger" => "Jolly+Lodger",
"Josefin Sans" => "Josefin+Sans",
"Josefin Slab" => "Josefin+Slab",
"Joti One" => "Joti+One",
"Judson" => "Judson",
"Julee" => "Julee",
"Julius Sans One" => "Julius+Sans+One",
"Junge" => "Junge",
"Jura" => "Jura",
"Just Another Hand" => "Just+Another+Hand",
"Just Me Again Down Here" => "Just+Me+Again+Down+Here",
"Kameron" => "Kameron",
"Karla" => "Karla",
"Kaushan Script" => "Kaushan+Script",
"Kavoon" => "Kavoon",
"Keania One" => "Keania+One",
"Kelly Slab" => "Kelly+Slab",
"Kenia" => "Kenia",
"Khmer" => "Khmer",
"Kite One" => "Kite+One",
"Knewave" => "Knewave",
"Kotta One" => "Kotta+One",
"Koulen" => "Koulen",
"Kranky" => "Kranky",
"Kreon" => "Kreon",
"Kristi" => "Kristi",
"Krona One" => "Krona+One",
"La Belle Aurore" => "La+Belle+Aurore",
"Lancelot" => "Lancelot",
"Lato" => "Lato",
"League Script" => "League+Script",
"Leckerli One" => "Leckerli+One",
"Ledger" => "Ledger",
"Lekton" => "Lekton",
"Lemon" => "Lemon",
"Libre Baskerville" => "Libre+Baskerville",
"Life Savers" => "Life+Savers",
"Lilita One" => "Lilita+One",
"Limelight" => "Limelight",
"Linden Hill" => "Linden+Hill",
"Lobster" => "Lobster",
"Lobster Two" => "Lobster+Two",
"Londrina Outline" => "Londrina+Outline",
"Londrina Shadow" => "Londrina+Shadow",
"Londrina Sketch" => "Londrina+Sketch",
"Londrina Solid" => "Londrina+Solid",
"Lora" => "Lora",
"Love Ya Like A Sister" => "Love+Ya+Like+A+Sister",
"Loved by the King" => "Loved+by+the+King",
"Lovers Quarrel" => "Lovers+Quarrel",
"Luckiest Guy" => "Luckiest+Guy",
"Lusitana" => "Lusitana",
"Lustria" => "Lustria",
"Macondo" => "Macondo",
"Macondo Swash Caps" => "Macondo+Swash+Caps",
"Magra" => "Magra",
"Maiden Orange" => "Maiden+Orange",
"Mako" => "Mako",
"Marcellus" => "Marcellus",
"Marcellus SC" => "Marcellus+SC",
"Marck Script" => "Marck+Script",
"Margarine" => "Margarine",
"Marko One" => "Marko+One",
"Marmelad" => "Marmelad",
"Marvel" => "Marvel",
"Mate" => "Mate",
"Mate SC" => "Mate+SC",
"Maven Pro" => "Maven+Pro",
"McLaren" => "McLaren",
"Meddon" => "Meddon",
"MedievalSharp" => "MedievalSharp",
"Medula One" => "Medula+One",
"Megrim" => "Megrim",
"Meie Script" => "Meie+Script",
"Merienda" => "Merienda",
"Merienda One" => "Merienda+One",
"Merriweather" => "Merriweather",
"Merriweather Sans" => "Merriweather+Sans",
"Metal" => "Metal",
"Metal Mania" => "Metal+Mania",
"Metamorphous" => "Metamorphous",
"Metrophobic" => "Metrophobic",
"Michroma" => "Michroma",
"Milonga" => "Milonga",
"Miltonian" => "Miltonian",
"Miltonian Tattoo" => "Miltonian+Tattoo",
"Miniver" => "Miniver",
"Miss Fajardose" => "Miss+Fajardose",
"Modern Antiqua" => "Modern+Antiqua",
"Molengo" => "Molengo",
"Molle" => "Molle",
"Monda" => "Monda",
"Monofett" => "Monofett",
"Monoton" => "Monoton",
"Monsieur La Doulaise" => "Monsieur+La+Doulaise",
"Montaga" => "Montaga",
"Montez" => "Montez",
"Montserrat" => "Montserrat",
"Montserrat Alternates" => "Montserrat+Alternates",
"Montserrat Subrayada" => "Montserrat+Subrayada",
"Moul" => "Moul",
"Moulpali" => "Moulpali",
"Mountains of Christmas" => "Mountains+of+Christmas",
"Mouse Memoirs" => "Mouse+Memoirs",
"Mr Bedfort" => "Mr+Bedfort",
"Mr Dafoe" => "Mr+Dafoe",
"Mr De Haviland" => "Mr+De+Haviland",
"Mrs Saint Delafield" => "Mrs+Saint+Delafield",
"Mrs Sheppards" => "Mrs+Sheppards",
"Muli" => "Muli",
"Mystery Quest" => "Mystery+Quest",
"Neucha" => "Neucha",
"Neuton" => "Neuton",
"New Rocker" => "New+Rocker",
"News Cycle" => "News+Cycle",
"Niconne" => "Niconne",
"Nixie One" => "Nixie+One",
"Nobile" => "Nobile",
"Nokora" => "Nokora",
"Norican" => "Norican",
"Nosifer" => "Nosifer",
"Nothing You Could Do" => "Nothing+You+Could+Do",
"Noticia Text" => "Noticia+Text",
"Nova Cut" => "Nova+Cut",
"Nova Flat" => "Nova+Flat",
"Nova Mono" => "Nova+Mono",
"Nova Oval" => "Nova+Oval",
"Nova Round" => "Nova+Round",
"Nova Script" => "Nova+Script",
"Nova Slim" => "Nova+Slim",
"Nova Square" => "Nova+Square",
"Numans" => "Numans",
"Nunito" => "Nunito",
"Odor Mean Chey" => "Odor+Mean+Chey",
"Offside" => "Offside",
"Old Standard TT" => "Old+Standard+TT",
"Oldenburg" => "Oldenburg",
"Oleo Script" => "Oleo+Script",
"Oleo Script Swash Caps" => "Oleo+Script+Swash+Caps",
"Open Sans" => "Open+Sans",
"Open Sans Condensed" => "Open+Sans+Condensed",
"Oranienbaum" => "Oranienbaum",
"Orbitron" => "Orbitron",
"Oregano" => "Oregano",
"Orienta" => "Orienta",
"Original Surfer" => "Original+Surfer",
"Oswald" => "Oswald",
"Over the Rainbow" => "Over+the+Rainbow",
"Overlock" => "Overlock",
"Overlock SC" => "Overlock+SC",
"Ovo" => "Ovo",
"Oxygen" => "Oxygen",
"Oxygen Mono" => "Oxygen+Mono",
"PT Mono" => "PT+Mono",
"PT Sans" => "PT+Sans",
"PT Sans Caption" => "PT+Sans+Caption",
"PT Sans Narrow" => "PT+Sans+Narrow",
"PT Serif" => "PT+Serif",
"PT Serif Caption" => "PT+Serif+Caption",
"Pacifico" => "Pacifico",
"Paprika" => "Paprika",
"Parisienne" => "Parisienne",
"Passero One" => "Passero+One",
"Passion One" => "Passion+One",
"Patrick Hand" => "Patrick+Hand",
"Patrick Hand SC" => "Patrick+Hand+SC",
"Patua One" => "Patua+One",
"Paytone One" => "Paytone+One",
"Peralta" => "Peralta",
"Permanent Marker" => "Permanent+Marker",
"Petit Formal Script" => "Petit+Formal+Script",
"Petrona" => "Petrona",
"Philosopher" => "Philosopher",
"Piedra" => "Piedra",
"Pinyon Script" => "Pinyon+Script",
"Pirata One" => "Pirata+One",
"Plaster" => "Plaster",
"Play" => "Play",
"Playball" => "Playball",
"Playfair Display" => "Playfair+Display",
"Playfair Display SC" => "Playfair+Display+SC",
"Podkova" => "Podkova",
"Poiret One" => "Poiret+One",
"Poller One" => "Poller+One",
"Poly" => "Poly",
"Pompiere" => "Pompiere",
"Pontano Sans" => "Pontano+Sans",
"Port Lligat Sans" => "Port+Lligat+Sans",
"Port Lligat Slab" => "Port+Lligat+Slab",
"Prata" => "Prata",
"Preahvihear" => "Preahvihear",
"Press Start 2P" => "Press+Start+2P",
"Princess Sofia" => "Princess+Sofia",
"Prociono" => "Prociono",
"Prosto One" => "Prosto+One",
"Puritan" => "Puritan",
"Purple Purse" => "Purple+Purse",
"Quando" => "Quando",
"Quantico" => "Quantico",
"Quattrocento" => "Quattrocento",
"Quattrocento Sans" => "Quattrocento+Sans",
"Questrial" => "Questrial",
"Quicksand" => "Quicksand",
"Quintessential" => "Quintessential",
"Qwigley" => "Qwigley",
"Racing Sans One" => "Racing+Sans+One",
"Radley" => "Radley",
"Raleway" => "Raleway",
"Raleway Dots" => "Raleway+Dots",
"Rambla" => "Rambla",
"Rammetto One" => "Rammetto+One",
"Ranchers" => "Ranchers",
"Rancho" => "Rancho",
"Rationale" => "Rationale",
"Redressed" => "Redressed",
"Reenie Beanie" => "Reenie+Beanie",
"Revalia" => "Revalia",
"Ribeye" => "Ribeye",
"Ribeye Marrow" => "Ribeye+Marrow",
"Righteous" => "Righteous",
"Risque" => "Risque",
"Roboto" => "Roboto",
"Roboto Condensed" => "Roboto+Condensed",
"Rochester" => "Rochester",
"Rock Salt" => "Rock+Salt",
"Rokkitt" => "Rokkitt",
"Romanesco" => "Romanesco",
"Ropa Sans" => "Ropa+Sans",
"Rosario" => "Rosario",
"Rosarivo" => "Rosarivo",
"Rouge Script" => "Rouge+Script",
"Ruda" => "Ruda",
"Rufina" => "Rufina",
"Ruge Boogie" => "Ruge+Boogie",
"Ruluko" => "Ruluko",
"Rum Raisin" => "Rum+Raisin",
"Ruslan Display" => "Ruslan+Display",
"Russo One" => "Russo+One",
"Ruthie" => "Ruthie",
"Rye" => "Rye",
"Sacramento" => "Sacramento",
"Sail" => "Sail",
"Salsa" => "Salsa",
"Sanchez" => "Sanchez",
"Sancreek" => "Sancreek",
"Sansita One" => "Sansita+One",
"Sarina" => "Sarina",
"Satisfy" => "Satisfy",
"Scada" => "Scada",
"Schoolbell" => "Schoolbell",
"Seaweed Script" => "Seaweed+Script",
"Sevillana" => "Sevillana",
"Seymour One" => "Seymour+One",
"Shadows Into Light" => "Shadows+Into+Light",
"Shadows Into Light Two" => "Shadows+Into+Light+Two",
"Shanti" => "Shanti",
"Share" => "Share",
"Share Tech" => "Share+Tech",
"Share Tech Mono" => "Share+Tech+Mono",
"Shojumaru" => "Shojumaru",
"Short Stack" => "Short+Stack",
"Siemreap" => "Siemreap",
"Sigmar One" => "Sigmar+One",
"Signika" => "Signika",
"Signika Negative" => "Signika+Negative",
"Simonetta" => "Simonetta",
"Sintony" => "Sintony",
"Sirin Stencil" => "Sirin+Stencil",
"Six Caps" => "Six+Caps",
"Skranji" => "Skranji",
"Slackey" => "Slackey",
"Smokum" => "Smokum",
"Smythe" => "Smythe",
"Sniglet" => "Sniglet",
"Snippet" => "Snippet",
"Snowburst One" => "Snowburst+One",
"Sofadi One" => "Sofadi+One",
"Sofia" => "Sofia",
"Sonsie One" => "Sonsie+One",
"Sorts Mill Goudy" => "Sorts+Mill+Goudy",
"Source Code Pro" => "Source+Code+Pro",
"Source Sans Pro" => "Source+Sans+Pro",
"Special Elite" => "Special+Elite",
"Spicy Rice" => "Spicy+Rice",
"Spinnaker" => "Spinnaker",
"Spirax" => "Spirax",
"Squada One" => "Squada+One",
"Stalemate" => "Stalemate",
"Stalinist One" => "Stalinist+One",
"Stardos Stencil" => "Stardos+Stencil",
"Stint Ultra Condensed" => "Stint+Ultra+Condensed",
"Stint Ultra Expanded" => "Stint+Ultra+Expanded",
"Stoke" => "Stoke",
"Strait" => "Strait",
"Sue Ellen Francisco" => "Sue+Ellen+Francisco",
"Sunshiney" => "Sunshiney",
"Supermercado One" => "Supermercado+One",
"Suwannaphum" => "Suwannaphum",
"Swanky and Moo Moo" => "Swanky+and+Moo+Moo",
"Syncopate" => "Syncopate",
"Tangerine" => "Tangerine",
"Taprom" => "Taprom",
"Tauri" => "Tauri",
"Telex" => "Telex",
"Tenor Sans" => "Tenor+Sans",
"Text Me One" => "Text+Me+One",
"The Girl Next Door" => "The+Girl+Next+Door",
"Tienne" => "Tienne",
"Tinos" => "Tinos",
"Titan One" => "Titan+One",
"Titillium Web" => "Titillium+Web",
"Trade Winds" => "Trade+Winds",
"Trocchi" => "Trocchi",
"Trochut" => "Trochut",
"Trykker" => "Trykker",
"Tulpen One" => "Tulpen+One",
"Ubuntu" => "Ubuntu",
"Ubuntu Condensed" => "Ubuntu+Condensed",
"Ubuntu Mono" => "Ubuntu+Mono",
"Ultra" => "Ultra",
"Uncial Antiqua" => "Uncial+Antiqua",
"Underdog" => "Underdog",
"Unica One" => "Unica+One",
"UnifrakturCook" => "UnifrakturCook",
"UnifrakturMaguntia" => "UnifrakturMaguntia",
"Unkempt" => "Unkempt",
"Unlock" => "Unlock",
"Unna" => "Unna",
"VT323" => "VT323",
"Vampiro One" => "Vampiro+One",
"Varela" => "Varela",
"Varela Round" => "Varela+Round",
"Vast Shadow" => "Vast+Shadow",
"Vibur" => "Vibur",
"Vidaloka" => "Vidaloka",
"Viga" => "Viga",
"Voces" => "Voces",
"Volkhov" => "Volkhov",
"Vollkorn" => "Vollkorn",
"Voltaire" => "Voltaire",
"Waiting for the Sunrise" => "Waiting+for+the+Sunrise",
"Wallpoet" => "Wallpoet",
"Walter Turncoat" => "Walter+Turncoat",
"Warnes" => "Warnes",
"Wellfleet" => "Wellfleet",
"Wendy One" => "Wendy+One",
"Wire One" => "Wire+One",
"Yanone Kaffeesatz" => "Yanone+Kaffeesatz",
"Yellowtail" => "Yellowtail",
"Yeseva One" => "Yeseva+One",
"Yesteryear" => "Yesteryear",
"Zeyada" => "Zeyada",
);
```

Answer (score 1):

**19.12.2017**

```
$google_fonts = array (
'ABeeZee' => 'ABeeZee',
'Abel' => 'Abel',
'Abhaya Libre' => 'Abhaya+Libre',
'Abril Fatface' => 'Abril+Fatface',
'Aclonica' => 'Aclonica',
'Acme' => 'Acme',
'Actor' => 'Actor',
'Adamina' => 'Adamina',
'Advent Pro' => 'Advent+Pro',
'Aguafina Script' => 'Aguafina+Script',
'Akronim' => 'Akronim',
'Aladin' => 'Aladin',
'Aldrich' => 'Aldrich',
'Alef' => 'Alef',
'Alegreya' => 'Alegreya',
'Alegreya SC' => 'Alegreya+SC',
'Alegreya Sans' => 'Alegreya+Sans',
'Alegreya Sans SC' => 'Alegreya+Sans+SC',
'Alex Brush' => 'Alex+Brush',
'Alfa Slab One' => 'Alfa+Slab+One',
'Alice' => 'Alice',
'Alike' => 'Alike',
'Alike Angular' => 'Alike+Angular',
'Allan' => 'Allan',
'Allerta' => 'Allerta',
'Allerta Stencil' => 'Allerta+Stencil',
'Allura' => 'Allura',
'Almendra' => 'Almendra',
'Almendra Display' => 'Almendra+Display',
'Almendra SC' => 'Almendra+SC',
'Amarante' => 'Amarante',
'Amaranth' => 'Amaranth',
'Amatic SC' => 'Amatic+SC',
'Amethysta' => 'Amethysta',
'Amiko' => 'Amiko',
'Amiri' => 'Amiri',
'Amita' => 'Amita',
'Anaheim' => 'Anaheim',
'Andada' => 'Andada',
'Andika' => 'Andika',
'Angkor' => 'Angkor',
'Annie Use Your Telescope' => 'Annie+Use+Your+Telescope',
'Anonymous Pro' => 'Anonymous+Pro',
'Antic' => 'Antic',
'Antic Didone' => 'Antic+Didone',
'Antic Slab' => 'Antic+Slab',
'Anton' => 'Anton',
'Arapey' => 'Arapey',
'Arbutus' => 'Arbutus',
'Arbutus Slab' => 'Arbutus+Slab',
'Architects Daughter' => 'Architects+Daughter',
'Archivo' => 'Archivo',
'Archivo Black' => 'Archivo+Black',
'Archivo Narrow' => 'Archivo+Narrow',
'Aref Ruqaa' => 'Aref+Ruqaa',
'Arima Madurai' => 'Arima+Madurai',
'Arimo' => 'Arimo',
'Arizonia' => 'Arizonia',
'Armata' => 'Armata',
'Arsenal' => 'Arsenal',
'Artifika' => 'Artifika',
'Arvo' => 'Arvo',
'Arya' => 'Arya',
'Asap' => 'Asap',
'Asap Condensed' => 'Asap+Condensed',
'Asar' => 'Asar',
'Asset' => 'Asset',
'Assistant' => 'Assistant',
'Astloch' => 'Astloch',
'Asul' => 'Asul',
'Athiti' => 'Athiti',
'Atma' => 'Atma',
'Atomic Age' => 'Atomic+Age',
'Aubrey' => 'Aubrey',
'Audiowide' => 'Audiowide',
'Autour One' => 'Autour+One',
'Average' => 'Average',
'Average Sans' => 'Average+Sans',
'Averia Gruesa Libre' => 'Averia+Gruesa+Libre',
'Averia Libre' => 'Averia+Libre',
'Averia Sans Libre' => 'Averia+Sans+Libre',
'Averia Serif Libre' => 'Averia+Serif+Libre',
'Bad Script' => 'Bad+Script',
'Bahiana' => 'Bahiana',
'Baloo' => 'Baloo',
'Baloo Bhai' => 'Baloo+Bhai',
'Baloo Bhaijaan' => 'Baloo+Bhaijaan',
'Baloo Bhaina' => 'Baloo+Bhaina',
'Baloo Chettan' => 'Baloo+Chettan',
'Baloo Da' => 'Baloo+Da',
'Baloo Paaji' => 'Baloo+Paaji',
'Baloo Tamma' => 'Baloo+Tamma',
'Baloo Tammudu' => 'Baloo+Tammudu',
'Baloo Thambi' => 'Baloo+Thambi',
'Balthazar' => 'Balthazar',
'Bangers' => 'Bangers',
'Barlow' => 'Barlow',
'Barlow Condensed' => 'Barlow+Condensed',
'Barlow Semi Condensed' => 'Barlow+Semi+Condensed',
'Barrio' => 'Barrio',
'Basic' => 'Basic',
'Battambang' => 'Battambang',
'Baumans' => 'Baumans',
'Bayon' => 'Bayon',
'Belgrano' => 'Belgrano',
'Bellefair' => 'Bellefair',
'Belleza' => 'Belleza',
'BenchNine' => 'BenchNine',
'Bentham' => 'Bentham',
'Berkshire Swash' => 'Berkshire+Swash',
'Bevan' => 'Bevan',
'Bigelow Rules' => 'Bigelow+Rules',
'Bigshot One' => 'Bigshot+One',
'Bilbo' => 'Bilbo',
'Bilbo Swash Caps' => 'Bilbo+Swash+Caps',
'BioRhyme' => 'BioRhyme',
'BioRhyme Expanded' => 'BioRhyme+Expanded',
'Biryani' => 'Biryani',
'Bitter' => 'Bitter',
'Black Ops One' => 'Black+Ops+One',
'Bokor' => 'Bokor',
'Bonbon' => 'Bonbon',
'Boogaloo' => 'Boogaloo',
'Bowlby One' => 'Bowlby+One',
'Bowlby One SC' => 'Bowlby+One+SC',
'Brawler' => 'Brawler',
'Bree Serif' => 'Bree+Serif',
'Bubblegum Sans' => 'Bubblegum+Sans',
'Bubbler One' => 'Bubbler+One',
'Buda' => 'Buda',
'Buenard' => 'Buenard',
'Bungee' => 'Bungee',
'Bungee Hairline' => 'Bungee+Hairline',
'Bungee Inline' => 'Bungee+Inline',
'Bungee Outline' => 'Bungee+Outline',
'Bungee Shade' => 'Bungee+Shade',
'Butcherman' => 'Butcherman',
'Butterfly Kids' => 'Butterfly+Kids',
'Cabin' => 'Cabin',
'Cabin Condensed' => 'Cabin+Condensed',
'Cabin Sketch' => 'Cabin+Sketch',
'Caesar Dressing' => 'Caesar+Dressing',
'Cagliostro' => 'Cagliostro',
'Cairo' => 'Cairo',
'Calligraffitti' => 'Calligraffitti',
'Cambay' => 'Cambay',
'Cambo' => 'Cambo',
'Candal' => 'Candal',
'Cantarell' => 'Cantarell',
'Cantata One' => 'Cantata+One',
'Cantora One' => 'Cantora+One',
'Capriola' => 'Capriola',
'Cardo' => 'Cardo',
'Carme' => 'Carme',
'Carrois Gothic' => 'Carrois+Gothic',
'Carrois Gothic SC' => 'Carrois+Gothic+SC',
'Carter One' => 'Carter+One',
'Catamaran' => 'Catamaran',
'Caudex' => 'Caudex',
'Caveat' => 'Caveat',
'Caveat Brush' => 'Caveat+Brush',
'Cedarville Cursive' => 'Cedarville+Cursive',
'Ceviche One' => 'Ceviche+One',
'Changa' => 'Changa',
'Changa One' => 'Changa+One',
'Chango' => 'Chango',
'Chathura' => 'Chathura',
'Chau Philomene One' => 'Chau+Philomene+One',
'Chela One' => 'Chela+One',
'Chelsea Market' => 'Chelsea+Market',
'Chenla' => 'Chenla',
'Cherry Cream Soda' => 'Cherry+Cream+Soda',
'Cherry Swash' => 'Cherry+Swash',
'Chewy' => 'Chewy',
'Chicle' => 'Chicle',
'Chivo' => 'Chivo',
'Chonburi' => 'Chonburi',
'Cinzel' => 'Cinzel',
'Cinzel Decorative' => 'Cinzel+Decorative',
'Clicker Script' => 'Clicker+Script',
'Coda' => 'Coda',
'Coda Caption' => 'Coda+Caption',
'Codystar' => 'Codystar',
'Coiny' => 'Coiny',
'Combo' => 'Combo',
'Comfortaa' => 'Comfortaa',
'Coming Soon' => 'Coming+Soon',
'Concert One' => 'Concert+One',
'Condiment' => 'Condiment',
'Content' => 'Content',
'Contrail One' => 'Contrail+One',
'Convergence' => 'Convergence',
'Cookie' => 'Cookie',
'Copse' => 'Copse',
'Corben' => 'Corben',
'Cormorant' => 'Cormorant',
'Cormorant Garamond' => 'Cormorant+Garamond',
'Cormorant Infant' => 'Cormorant+Infant',
'Cormorant SC' => 'Cormorant+SC',
'Cormorant Unicase' => 'Cormorant+Unicase',
'Cormorant Upright' => 'Cormorant+Upright',
'Courgette' => 'Courgette',
'Cousine' => 'Cousine',
'Coustard' => 'Coustard',
'Covered By Your Grace' => 'Covered+By+Your+Grace',
'Crafty Girls' => 'Crafty+Girls',
'Creepster' => 'Creepster',
'Crete Round' => 'Crete+Round',
'Crimson Text' => 'Crimson+Text',
'Croissant One' => 'Croissant+One',
'Crushed' => 'Crushed',
'Cuprum' => 'Cuprum',
'Cutive' => 'Cutive',
'Cutive Mono' => 'Cutive+Mono',
'Damion' => 'Damion',
'Dancing Script' => 'Dancing+Script',
'Dangrek' => 'Dangrek',
'David Libre' => 'David+Libre',
'Dawning of a New Day' => 'Dawning+of+a+New+Day',
'Days One' => 'Days+One',
'Dekko' => 'Dekko',
'Delius' => 'Delius',
'Delius Swash Caps' => 'Delius+Swash+Caps',
'Delius Unicase' => 'Delius+Unicase',
'Della Respira' => 'Della+Respira',
'Denk One' => 'Denk+One',
'Devonshire' => 'Devonshire',
'Dhurjati' => 'Dhurjati',
'Didact Gothic' => 'Didact+Gothic',
'Diplomata' => 'Diplomata',
'Diplomata SC' => 'Diplomata+SC',
'Domine' => 'Domine',
'Donegal One' => 'Donegal+One',
'Doppio One' => 'Doppio+One',
'Dorsa' => 'Dorsa',
'Dosis' => 'Dosis',
'Dr Sugiyama' => 'Dr+Sugiyama',
'Duru Sans' => 'Duru+Sans',
'Dynalight' => 'Dynalight',
'EB Garamond' => 'EB+Garamond',
'Eagle Lake' => 'Eagle+Lake',
'Eater' => 'Eater',
'Economica' => 'Economica',
'Eczar' => 'Eczar',
'El Messiri' => 'El+Messiri',
'Electrolize' => 'Electrolize',
'Elsie' => 'Elsie',
'Elsie Swash Caps' => 'Elsie+Swash+Caps',
'Emblema One' => 'Emblema+One',
'Emilys Candy' => 'Emilys+Candy',
'Encode Sans' => 'Encode+Sans',
'Encode Sans Condensed' => 'Encode+Sans+Condensed',
'Encode Sans Expanded' => 'Encode+Sans+Expanded',
'Encode Sans Semi Condensed' => 'Encode+Sans+Semi+Condensed',
'Encode Sans Semi Expanded' => 'Encode+Sans+Semi+Expanded',
'Engagement' => 'Engagement',
'Englebert' => 'Englebert',
'Enriqueta' => 'Enriqueta',
'Erica One' => 'Erica+One',
'Esteban' => 'Esteban',
'Euphoria Script' => 'Euphoria+Script',
'Ewert' => 'Ewert',
'Exo' => 'Exo',
'Exo 2' => 'Exo+2',
'Expletus Sans' => 'Expletus+Sans',
'Fanwood Text' => 'Fanwood+Text',
'Farsan' => 'Farsan',
'Fascinate' => 'Fascinate',
'Fascinate Inline' => 'Fascinate+Inline',
'Faster One' => 'Faster+One',
'Fasthand' => 'Fasthand',
'Fauna One' => 'Fauna+One',
'Faustina' => 'Faustina',
'Federant' => 'Federant',
'Federo' => 'Federo',
'Felipa' => 'Felipa',
'Fenix' => 'Fenix',
'Finger Paint' => 'Finger+Paint',
'Fira Mono' => 'Fira+Mono',
'Fira Sans' => 'Fira+Sans',
'Fira Sans Condensed' => 'Fira+Sans+Condensed',
'Fira Sans Extra Condensed' => 'Fira+Sans+Extra+Condensed',
'Fjalla One' => 'Fjalla+One',
'Fjord One' => 'Fjord+One',
'Flamenco' => 'Flamenco',
'Flavors' => 'Flavors',
'Fondamento' => 'Fondamento',
'Fontdiner Swanky' => 'Fontdiner+Swanky',
'Forum' => 'Forum',
'Francois One' => 'Francois+One',
'Frank Ruhl Libre' => 'Frank+Ruhl+Libre',
'Freckle Face' => 'Freckle+Face',
'Fredericka the Great' => 'Fredericka+the+Great',
'Fredoka One' => 'Fredoka+One',
'Freehand' => 'Freehand',
'Fresca' => 'Fresca',
'Frijole' => 'Frijole',
'Fruktur' => 'Fruktur',
'Fugaz One' => 'Fugaz+One',
'GFS Didot' => 'GFS+Didot',
'GFS Neohellenic' => 'GFS+Neohellenic',
'Gabriela' => 'Gabriela',
'Gafata' => 'Gafata',
'Galada' => 'Galada',
'Galdeano' => 'Galdeano',
'Galindo' => 'Galindo',
'Gentium Basic' => 'Gentium+Basic',
'Gentium Book Basic' => 'Gentium+Book+Basic',
'Geo' => 'Geo',
'Geostar' => 'Geostar',
'Geostar Fill' => 'Geostar+Fill',
'Germania One' => 'Germania+One',
'Gidugu' => 'Gidugu',
'Gilda Display' => 'Gilda+Display',
'Give You Glory' => 'Give+You+Glory',
'Glass Antiqua' => 'Glass+Antiqua',
'Glegoo' => 'Glegoo',
'Gloria Hallelujah' => 'Gloria+Hallelujah',
'Goblin One' => 'Goblin+One',
'Gochi Hand' => 'Gochi+Hand',
'Gorditas' => 'Gorditas',
'Goudy Bookletter 1911' => 'Goudy+Bookletter+1911',
'Graduate' => 'Graduate',
'Grand Hotel' => 'Grand+Hotel',
'Gravitas One' => 'Gravitas+One',
'Great Vibes' => 'Great+Vibes',
'Griffy' => 'Griffy',
'Gruppo' => 'Gruppo',
'Gudea' => 'Gudea',
'Gurajada' => 'Gurajada',
'Habibi' => 'Habibi',
'Halant' => 'Halant',
'Hammersmith One' => 'Hammersmith+One',
'Hanalei' => 'Hanalei',
'Hanalei Fill' => 'Hanalei+Fill',
'Handlee' => 'Handlee',
'Hanuman' => 'Hanuman',
'Happy Monkey' => 'Happy+Monkey',
'Harmattan' => 'Harmattan',
'Headland One' => 'Headland+One',
'Heebo' => 'Heebo',
'Henny Penny' => 'Henny+Penny',
'Herr Von Muellerhoff' => 'Herr+Von+Muellerhoff',
'Hind' => 'Hind',
'Hind Guntur' => 'Hind+Guntur',
'Hind Madurai' => 'Hind+Madurai',
'Hind Siliguri' => 'Hind+Siliguri',
'Hind Vadodara' => 'Hind+Vadodara',
'Holtwood One SC' => 'Holtwood+One+SC',
'Homemade Apple' => 'Homemade+Apple',
'Homenaje' => 'Homenaje',
'IM Fell DW Pica' => 'IM+Fell+DW+Pica',
'IM Fell DW Pica SC' => 'IM+Fell+DW+Pica+SC',
'IM Fell Double Pica' => 'IM+Fell+Double+Pica',
'IM Fell Double Pica SC' => 'IM+Fell+Double+Pica+SC',
'IM Fell English' => 'IM+Fell+English',
'IM Fell English SC' => 'IM+Fell+English+SC',
'IM Fell French Canon' => 'IM+Fell+French+Canon',
'IM Fell French Canon SC' => 'IM+Fell+French+Canon+SC',
'IM Fell Great Primer' => 'IM+Fell+Great+Primer',
'IM Fell Great Primer SC' => 'IM+Fell+Great+Primer+SC',
'Iceberg' => 'Iceberg',
'Iceland' => 'Iceland',
'Imprima' => 'Imprima',
'Inconsolata' => 'Inconsolata',
'Inder' => 'Inder',
'Indie Flower' => 'Indie+Flower',
'Inika' => 'Inika',
'Inknut Antiqua' => 'Inknut+Antiqua',
'Irish Grover' => 'Irish+Grover',
'Istok Web' => 'Istok+Web',
'Italiana' => 'Italiana',
'Italianno' => 'Italianno',
'Itim' => 'Itim',
'Jacques Francois' => 'Jacques+Francois',
'Jacques Francois Shadow' => 'Jacques+Francois+Shadow',
'Jaldi' => 'Jaldi',
'Jim Nightshade' => 'Jim+Nightshade',
'Jockey One' => 'Jockey+One',
'Jolly Lodger' => 'Jolly+Lodger',
'Jomhuria' => 'Jomhuria',
'Josefin Sans' => 'Josefin+Sans',
'Josefin Slab' => 'Josefin+Slab',
'Joti One' => 'Joti+One',
'Judson' => 'Judson',
'Julee' => 'Julee',
'Julius Sans One' => 'Julius+Sans+One',
'Junge' => 'Junge',
'Jura' => 'Jura',
'Just Another Hand' => 'Just+Another+Hand',
'Just Me Again Down Here' => 'Just+Me+Again+Down+Here',
'Kadwa' => 'Kadwa',
'Kalam' => 'Kalam',
'Kameron' => 'Kameron',
'Kanit' => 'Kanit',
'Kantumruy' => 'Kantumruy',
'Karla' => 'Karla',
'Karma' => 'Karma',
'Katibeh' => 'Katibeh',
'Kaushan Script' => 'Kaushan+Script',
'Kavivanar' => 'Kavivanar',
'Kavoon' => 'Kavoon',
'Kdam Thmor' => 'Kdam+Thmor',
'Keania One' => 'Keania+One',
'Kelly Slab' => 'Kelly+Slab',
'Kenia' => 'Kenia',
'Khand' => 'Khand',
'Khmer' => 'Khmer',
'Khula' => 'Khula',
'Kite One' => 'Kite+One',
'Knewave' => 'Knewave',
'Kotta One' => 'Kotta+One',
'Koulen' => 'Koulen',
'Kranky' => 'Kranky',
'Kreon' => 'Kreon',
'Kristi' => 'Kristi',
'Krona One' => 'Krona+One',
'Kumar One' => 'Kumar+One',
'Kumar One Outline' => 'Kumar+One+Outline',
'Kurale' => 'Kurale',
'La Belle Aurore' => 'La+Belle+Aurore',
'Laila' => 'Laila',
'Lakki Reddy' => 'Lakki+Reddy',
'Lalezar' => 'Lalezar',
'Lancelot' => 'Lancelot',
'Lateef' => 'Lateef',
'Lato' => 'Lato',
'League Script' => 'League+Script',
'Leckerli One' => 'Leckerli+One',
'Ledger' => 'Ledger',
'Lekton' => 'Lekton',
'Lemon' => 'Lemon',
'Lemonada' => 'Lemonada',
'Libre Barcode 128' => 'Libre+Barcode+128',
'Libre Barcode 128 Text' => 'Libre+Barcode+128+Text',
'Libre Barcode 39' => 'Libre+Barcode+39',
'Libre Barcode 39 Extended' => 'Libre+Barcode+39+Extended',
'Libre Barcode 39 Extended Text' => 'Libre+Barcode+39+Extended+Text',
'Libre Barcode 39 Text' => 'Libre+Barcode+39+Text',
'Libre Baskerville' => 'Libre+Baskerville',
'Libre Franklin' => 'Libre+Franklin',
'Life Savers' => 'Life+Savers',
'Lilita One' => 'Lilita+One',
'Lily Script One' => 'Lily+Script+One',
'Limelight' => 'Limelight',
'Linden Hill' => 'Linden+Hill',
'Lobster' => 'Lobster',
'Lobster Two' => 'Lobster+Two',
'Londrina Outline' => 'Londrina+Outline',
'Londrina Shadow' => 'Londrina+Shadow',
'Londrina Sketch' => 'Londrina+Sketch',
'Londrina Solid' => 'Londrina+Solid',
'Lora' => 'Lora',
'Love Ya Like A Sister' => 'Love+Ya+Like+A+Sister',
'Loved by the King' => 'Loved+by+the+King',
'Lovers Quarrel' => 'Lovers+Quarrel',
'Luckiest Guy' => 'Luckiest+Guy',
'Lusitana' => 'Lusitana',
'Lustria' => 'Lustria',
'Macondo' => 'Macondo',
'Macondo Swash Caps' => 'Macondo+Swash+Caps',
'Mada' => 'Mada',
'Magra' => 'Magra',
'Maiden Orange' => 'Maiden+Orange',
'Maitree' => 'Maitree',
'Mako' => 'Mako',
'Mallanna' => 'Mallanna',
'Mandali' => 'Mandali',
'Manuale' => 'Manuale',
'Marcellus' => 'Marcellus',
'Marcellus SC' => 'Marcellus+SC',
'Marck Script' => 'Marck+Script',
'Margarine' => 'Margarine',
'Marko One' => 'Marko+One',
'Marmelad' => 'Marmelad',
'Martel' => 'Martel',
'Martel Sans' => 'Martel+Sans',
'Marvel' => 'Marvel',
'Mate' => 'Mate',
'Mate SC' => 'Mate+SC',
'Maven Pro' => 'Maven+Pro',
'McLaren' => 'McLaren',
'Meddon' => 'Meddon',
'MedievalSharp' => 'MedievalSharp',
'Medula One' => 'Medula+One',
'Meera Inimai' => 'Meera+Inimai',
'Megrim' => 'Megrim',
'Meie Script' => 'Meie+Script',
'Merienda' => 'Merienda',
'Merienda One' => 'Merienda+One',
'Merriweather' => 'Merriweather',
'Merriweather Sans' => 'Merriweather+Sans',
'Metal' => 'Metal',
'Metal Mania' => 'Metal+Mania',
'Metamorphous' => 'Metamorphous',
'Metrophobic' => 'Metrophobic',
'Michroma' => 'Michroma',
'Milonga' => 'Milonga',
'Miltonian' => 'Miltonian',
'Miltonian Tattoo' => 'Miltonian+Tattoo',
'Miniver' => 'Miniver',
'Miriam Libre' => 'Miriam+Libre',
'Mirza' => 'Mirza',
'Miss Fajardose' => 'Miss+Fajardose',
'Mitr' => 'Mitr',
'Modak' => 'Modak',
'Modern Antiqua' => 'Modern+Antiqua',
'Mogra' => 'Mogra',
'Molengo' => 'Molengo',
'Molle' => 'Molle',
'Monda' => 'Monda',
'Monofett' => 'Monofett',
'Monoton' => 'Monoton',
'Monsieur La Doulaise' => 'Monsieur+La+Doulaise',
'Montaga' => 'Montaga',
'Montez' => 'Montez',
'Montserrat' => 'Montserrat',
'Montserrat Alternates' => 'Montserrat+Alternates',
'Montserrat Subrayada' => 'Montserrat+Subrayada',
'Moul' => 'Moul',
'Moulpali' => 'Moulpali',
'Mountains of Christmas' => 'Mountains+of+Christmas',
'Mouse Memoirs' => 'Mouse+Memoirs',
'Mr Bedfort' => 'Mr+Bedfort',
'Mr Dafoe' => 'Mr+Dafoe',
'Mr De Haviland' => 'Mr+De+Haviland',
'Mrs Saint Delafield' => 'Mrs+Saint+Delafield',
'Mrs Sheppards' => 'Mrs+Sheppards',
'Mukta' => 'Mukta',
'Mukta Mahee' => 'Mukta+Mahee',
'Mukta Malar' => 'Mukta+Malar',
'Mukta Vaani' => 'Mukta+Vaani',
'Muli' => 'Muli',
'Mystery Quest' => 'Mystery+Quest',
'NTR' => 'NTR',
'Neucha' => 'Neucha',
'Neuton' => 'Neuton',
'New Rocker' => 'New+Rocker',
'News Cycle' => 'News+Cycle',
'Niconne' => 'Niconne',
'Nixie One' => 'Nixie+One',
'Nobile' => 'Nobile',
'Nokora' => 'Nokora',
'Norican' => 'Norican',
'Nosifer' => 'Nosifer',
'Nothing You Could Do' => 'Nothing+You+Could+Do',
'Noticia Text' => 'Noticia+Text',
'Noto Sans' => 'Noto+Sans',
'Noto Serif' => 'Noto+Serif',
'Nova Cut' => 'Nova+Cut',
'Nova Flat' => 'Nova+Flat',
'Nova Mono' => 'Nova+Mono',
'Nova Oval' => 'Nova+Oval',
'Nova Round' => 'Nova+Round',
'Nova Script' => 'Nova+Script',
'Nova Slim' => 'Nova+Slim',
'Nova Square' => 'Nova+Square',
'Numans' => 'Numans',
'Nunito' => 'Nunito',
'Nunito Sans' => 'Nunito+Sans',
'Odor Mean Chey' => 'Odor+Mean+Chey',
'Offside' => 'Offside',
'Old Standard TT' => 'Old+Standard+TT',
'Oldenburg' => 'Oldenburg',
'Oleo Script' => 'Oleo+Script',
'Oleo Script Swash Caps' => 'Oleo+Script+Swash+Caps',
'Open Sans' => 'Open+Sans',
'Open Sans Condensed' => 'Open+Sans+Condensed',
'Oranienbaum' => 'Oranienbaum',
'Orbitron' => 'Orbitron',
'Oregano' => 'Oregano',
'Orienta' => 'Orienta',
'Original Surfer' => 'Original+Surfer',
'Oswald' => 'Oswald',
'Over the Rainbow' => 'Over+the+Rainbow',
'Overlock' => 'Overlock',
'Overlock SC' => 'Overlock+SC',
'Overpass' => 'Overpass',
'Overpass Mono' => 'Overpass+Mono',
'Ovo' => 'Ovo',
'Oxygen' => 'Oxygen',
'Oxygen Mono' => 'Oxygen+Mono',
'PT Mono' => 'PT+Mono',
'PT Sans' => 'PT+Sans',
'PT Sans Caption' => 'PT+Sans+Caption',
'PT Sans Narrow' => 'PT+Sans+Narrow',
'PT Serif' => 'PT+Serif',
'PT Serif Caption' => 'PT+Serif+Caption',
'Pacifico' => 'Pacifico',
'Padauk' => 'Padauk',
'Palanquin' => 'Palanquin',
'Palanquin Dark' => 'Palanquin+Dark',
'Pangolin' => 'Pangolin',
'Paprika' => 'Paprika',
'Parisienne' => 'Parisienne',
'Passero One' => 'Passero+One',
'Passion One' => 'Passion+One',
'Pathway Gothic One' => 'Pathway+Gothic+One',
'Patrick Hand' => 'Patrick+Hand',
'Patrick Hand SC' => 'Patrick+Hand+SC',
'Pattaya' => 'Pattaya',
'Patua One' => 'Patua+One',
'Pavanam' => 'Pavanam',
'Paytone One' => 'Paytone+One',
'Peddana' => 'Peddana',
'Peralta' => 'Peralta',
'Permanent Marker' => 'Permanent+Marker',
'Petit Formal Script' => 'Petit+Formal+Script',
'Petrona' => 'Petrona',
'Philosopher' => 'Philosopher',
'Piedra' => 'Piedra',
'Pinyon Script' => 'Pinyon+Script',
'Pirata One' => 'Pirata+One',
'Plaster' => 'Plaster',
'Play' => 'Play',
'Playball' => 'Playball',
'Playfair Display' => 'Playfair+Display',
'Playfair Display SC' => 'Playfair+Display+SC',
'Podkova' => 'Podkova',
'Poiret One' => 'Poiret+One',
'Poller One' => 'Poller+One',
'Poly' => 'Poly',
'Pompiere' => 'Pompiere',
'Pontano Sans' => 'Pontano+Sans',
'Poppins' => 'Poppins',
'Port Lligat Sans' => 'Port+Lligat+Sans',
'Port Lligat Slab' => 'Port+Lligat+Slab',
'Pragati Narrow' => 'Pragati+Narrow',
'Prata' => 'Prata',
'Preahvihear' => 'Preahvihear',
'Press Start 2P' => 'Press+Start+2P',
'Pridi' => 'Pridi',
'Princess Sofia' => 'Princess+Sofia',
'Prociono' => 'Prociono',
'Prompt' => 'Prompt',
'Prosto One' => 'Prosto+One',
'Proza Libre' => 'Proza+Libre',
'Puritan' => 'Puritan',
'Purple Purse' => 'Purple+Purse',
'Quando' => 'Quando',
'Quantico' => 'Quantico',
'Quattrocento' => 'Quattrocento',
'Quattrocento Sans' => 'Quattrocento+Sans',
'Questrial' => 'Questrial',
'Quicksand' => 'Quicksand',
'Quintessential' => 'Quintessential',
'Qwigley' => 'Qwigley',
'Racing Sans One' => 'Racing+Sans+One',
'Radley' => 'Radley',
'Rajdhani' => 'Rajdhani',
'Rakkas' => 'Rakkas',
'Raleway' => 'Raleway',
'Raleway Dots' => 'Raleway+Dots',
'Ramabhadra' => 'Ramabhadra',
'Ramaraja' => 'Ramaraja',
'Rambla' => 'Rambla',
'Rammetto One' => 'Rammetto+One',
'Ranchers' => 'Ranchers',
'Rancho' => 'Rancho',
'Ranga' => 'Ranga',
'Rasa' => 'Rasa',
'Rationale' => 'Rationale',
'Ravi Prakash' => 'Ravi+Prakash',
'Redressed' => 'Redressed',
'Reem Kufi' => 'Reem+Kufi',
'Reenie Beanie' => 'Reenie+Beanie',
'Revalia' => 'Revalia',
'Rhodium Libre' => 'Rhodium+Libre',
'Ribeye' => 'Ribeye',
'Ribeye Marrow' => 'Ribeye+Marrow',
'Righteous' => 'Righteous',
'Risque' => 'Risque',
'Roboto' => 'Roboto',
'Roboto Condensed' => 'Roboto+Condensed',
'Roboto Mono' => 'Roboto+Mono',
'Roboto Slab' => 'Roboto+Slab',
'Rochester' => 'Rochester',
'Rock Salt' => 'Rock+Salt',
'Rokkitt' => 'Rokkitt',
'Romanesco' => 'Romanesco',
'Ropa Sans' => 'Ropa+Sans',
'Rosario' => 'Rosario',
'Rosarivo' => 'Rosarivo',
'Rouge Script' => 'Rouge+Script',
'Rozha One' => 'Rozha+One',
'Rubik' => 'Rubik',
'Rubik Mono One' => 'Rubik+Mono+One',
'Ruda' => 'Ruda',
'Rufina' => 'Rufina',
'Ruge Boogie' => 'Ruge+Boogie',
'Ruluko' => 'Ruluko',
'Rum Raisin' => 'Rum+Raisin',
'Ruslan Display' => 'Ruslan+Display',
'Russo One' => 'Russo+One',
'Ruthie' => 'Ruthie',
'Rye' => 'Rye',
'Sacramento' => 'Sacramento',
'Sahitya' => 'Sahitya',
'Sail' => 'Sail',
'Saira' => 'Saira',
'Saira Condensed' => 'Saira+Condensed',
'Saira Extra Condensed' => 'Saira+Extra+Condensed',
'Saira Semi Condensed' => 'Saira+Semi+Condensed',
'Salsa' => 'Salsa',
'Sanchez' => 'Sanchez',
'Sancreek' => 'Sancreek',
'Sansita' => 'Sansita',
'Sarala' => 'Sarala',
'Sarina' => 'Sarina',
'Sarpanch' => 'Sarpanch',
'Satisfy' => 'Satisfy',
'Scada' => 'Scada',
'Scheherazade' => 'Scheherazade',
'Schoolbell' => 'Schoolbell',
'Scope One' => 'Scope+One',
'Seaweed Script' => 'Seaweed+Script',
'Secular One' => 'Secular+One',
'Sedgwick Ave' => 'Sedgwick+Ave',
'Sedgwick Ave Display' => 'Sedgwick+Ave+Display',
'Sevillana' => 'Sevillana',
'Seymour One' => 'Seymour+One',
'Shadows Into Light' => 'Shadows+Into+Light',
'Shadows Into Light Two' => 'Shadows+Into+Light+Two',
'Shanti' => 'Shanti',
'Share' => 'Share',
'Share Tech' => 'Share+Tech',
'Share Tech Mono' => 'Share+Tech+Mono',
'Shojumaru' => 'Shojumaru',
'Short Stack' => 'Short+Stack',
'Shrikhand' => 'Shrikhand',
'Siemreap' => 'Siemreap',
'Sigmar One' => 'Sigmar+One',
'Signika' => 'Signika',
'Signika Negative' => 'Signika+Negative',
'Simonetta' => 'Simonetta',
'Sintony' => 'Sintony',
'Sirin Stencil' => 'Sirin+Stencil',
'Six Caps' => 'Six+Caps',
'Skranji' => 'Skranji',
'Slabo 13px' => 'Slabo+13px',
'Slabo 27px' => 'Slabo+27px',
'Slackey' => 'Slackey',
'Smokum' => 'Smokum',
'Smythe' => 'Smythe',
'Sniglet' => 'Sniglet',
'Snippet' => 'Snippet',
'Snowburst One' => 'Snowburst+One',
'Sofadi One' => 'Sofadi+One',
'Sofia' => 'Sofia',
'Sonsie One' => 'Sonsie+One',
'Sorts Mill Goudy' => 'Sorts+Mill+Goudy',
'Source Code Pro' => 'Source+Code+Pro',
'Source Sans Pro' => 'Source+Sans+Pro',
'Source Serif Pro' => 'Source+Serif+Pro',
'Space Mono' => 'Space+Mono',
'Special Elite' => 'Special+Elite',
'Spectral' => 'Spectral',
'Spectral SC' => 'Spectral+SC',
'Spicy Rice' => 'Spicy+Rice',
'Spinnaker' => 'Spinnaker',
'Spirax' => 'Spirax',
'Squada One' => 'Squada+One',
'Sree Krushnadevaraya' => 'Sree+Krushnadevaraya',
'Sriracha' => 'Sriracha',
'Stalemate' => 'Stalemate',
'Stalinist One' => 'Stalinist+One',
'Stardos Stencil' => 'Stardos+Stencil',
'Stint Ultra Condensed' => 'Stint+Ultra+Condensed',
'Stint Ultra Expanded' => 'Stint+Ultra+Expanded',
'Stoke' => 'Stoke',
'Strait' => 'Strait',
'Sue Ellen Francisco' => 'Sue+Ellen+Francisco',
'Suez One' => 'Suez+One',
'Sumana' => 'Sumana',
'Sunshiney' => 'Sunshiney',
'Supermercado One' => 'Supermercado+One',
'Sura' => 'Sura',
'Suranna' => 'Suranna',
'Suravaram' => 'Suravaram',
'Suwannaphum' => 'Suwannaphum',
'Swanky and Moo Moo' => 'Swanky+and+Moo+Moo',
'Syncopate' => 'Syncopate',
'Tangerine' => 'Tangerine',
'Taprom' => 'Taprom',
'Tauri' => 'Tauri',
'Taviraj' => 'Taviraj',
'Teko' => 'Teko',
'Telex' => 'Telex',
'Tenali Ramakrishna' => 'Tenali+Ramakrishna',
'Tenor Sans' => 'Tenor+Sans',
'Text Me One' => 'Text+Me+One',
'The Girl Next Door' => 'The+Girl+Next+Door',
'Tienne' => 'Tienne',
'Tillana' => 'Tillana',
'Timmana' => 'Timmana',
'Tinos' => 'Tinos',
'Titan One' => 'Titan+One',
'Titillium Web' => 'Titillium+Web',
'Trade Winds' => 'Trade+Winds',
'Trirong' => 'Trirong',
'Trocchi' => 'Trocchi',
'Trochut' => 'Trochut',
'Trykker' => 'Trykker',
'Tulpen One' => 'Tulpen+One',
'Ubuntu' => 'Ubuntu',
'Ubuntu Condensed' => 'Ubuntu+Condensed',
'Ubuntu Mono' => 'Ubuntu+Mono',
'Ultra' => 'Ultra',
'Uncial Antiqua' => 'Uncial+Antiqua',
'Underdog' => 'Underdog',
'Unica One' => 'Unica+One',
'UnifrakturCook' => 'UnifrakturCook',
'UnifrakturMaguntia' => 'UnifrakturMaguntia',
'Unkempt' => 'Unkempt',
'Unlock' => 'Unlock',
'Unna' => 'Unna',
'VT323' => 'VT323',
'Vampiro One' => 'Vampiro+One',
'Varela' => 'Varela',
'Varela Round' => 'Varela+Round',
'Vast Shadow' => 'Vast+Shadow',
'Vesper Libre' => 'Vesper+Libre',
'Vibur' => 'Vibur',
'Vidaloka' => 'Vidaloka',
'Viga' => 'Viga',
'Voces' => 'Voces',
'Volkhov' => 'Volkhov',
'Vollkorn' => 'Vollkorn',
'Vollkorn SC' => 'Vollkorn+SC',
'Voltaire' => 'Voltaire',
'Waiting for the Sunrise' => 'Waiting+for+the+Sunrise',
'Wallpoet' => 'Wallpoet',
'Walter Turncoat' => 'Walter+Turncoat',
'Warnes' => 'Warnes',
'Wellfleet' => 'Wellfleet',
'Wendy One' => 'Wendy+One',
'Wire One' => 'Wire+One',
'Work Sans' => 'Work+Sans',
'Yanone Kaffeesatz' => 'Yanone+Kaffeesatz',
'Yantramanav' => 'Yantramanav',
'Yatra One' => 'Yatra+One',
'Yellowtail' => 'Yellowtail',
'Yeseva One' => 'Yeseva+One',
'Yesteryear' => 'Yesteryear',
'Yrsa' => 'Yrsa',
'Zeyada' => 'Zeyada',
'Zilla Slab' => 'Zilla+Slab',
'Zilla Slab Highlight' => 'Zilla+Slab+Highlight',
);
```